# MySQL: How do I GROUP BY 2 fields and return the maximum of those 2 fields in another?

Tags: mysql, sql

| Route | Incident | delay_minute |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 63 | Operator | 60 |
| 63 | Operator | 24 |
| 63 | Mechanical | 89 |
| 54 | Operator | 70 |
| 54 | Sanitation | 34 |
| 54 | Operator | 12 |

From the example table above, I want to return **one row per route** with their **most common** type/form of Incident. Such that it would look like this:

| Route | Incident |
| --- | --- |
| 63 | Operator |
| 54 | Operator |

I have tried the following query, but I am unsure whether or not it returns the most common form of Incident per route:

```
SELECT Route
   , Incident
FROM bus_delay;
```

I have also attempted to use `COUNT(DISTINCT)` but I require the Incident type returned as string, per route:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Route
    , Incident
    , COUNT(Incident) AS count_incident
FROM bus_delay
GROUP BY Incident
    , Route;
```

How do I query such a table to return one row per Route, with that row only showing the most common form of Incident for that Route?

Comment: This is described as the groupwize maximum problem - there's a chapter in the MySQL on how to solve this - although they keep changing which solution they publish - there are at least 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
select Route, Incident
from
(
  select Route, Incident, 
       row_number() over (partition by Route order by count(*) desc) rn
  from bus_delay
  group by Route, Incident
) T
where rn=1
```

If there could be a ties in the Incident counts per route (multiple counts with the same value) and you want to return all of Incident with the maximum count then use `DENSE_RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`.

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/YGwu5tUP).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Z.Route,Z.Incident  FROM
(
  SELECT C.Route,C.Incident,
   ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY C.Route,C.Incident ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))XCOL
  FROM YOUR_TABLE AS C
)Z WHERE Z.XCOL>1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `WINDOW` function and `CTE`

```
WITH CTE as(
   SELECT
      Route,    Incident,   delay_minute,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Route,     Inciden ORDER BY delay_minute DESC) rn
   FROM bus_delay)
SELECT
Route,  Incident,   delay_minute
FROM CTE WHERE rn = 1
```